# How to Store DateTime as a timestamp - Firebase flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I use this method to send time to firestore,
But the type of "time" filed in the collection is int.

```
Map<String, dynamic> Qnote= {
      "note": note,
      "sender": username,
      "uid": uid,
      "time": DateTime.now().microsecondsSinceEpoch, // <---- here
    };

    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("Note").doc(noteId).collection("QuickNote").add(Qnote);
```

[image]

How to save time field as timestamp in collection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is `Timestamp.fromDate(DateTime.now())`

```
Map<String, dynamic> Qnote= {
      "note": note,
      "sender": username,
      "uid": uid,
      "time": Timestamp.fromDate(DateTime.now()), // <---- here
    };
```

Comment: DateTime.now().microsecondsSinceEpoch, this value can't be become a time again?

Comment: @HoRiz There is a [`DateTime.fromMicrosecondsSinceEpoch` constructor](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/DateTime/DateTime.fromMicrosecondsSinceEpoch.html).